# how to change xmldataprovider source in wpf at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, xmldataprovider

I made an application which draws a tree of organization based on values from an xml file.

The xaml file goes like this :

```
<Window.Resources>


    <!-- The Org Chart Data-->
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="organization"  Source="model.xml" />

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ListBorder" Color="#FF7F9DB9"/>

    <!-- The Style for Nodes -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type draw:Node}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
        ---------------------------------------------------------
```

I want to be able to change the source at runtime by selecting a xml file from openfiledialog (like button click) how do i do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the `XmlDataProvider` instance by writing `(XmlDataProvider)this.Resources["organization"]` in the code file.

You can then set the [`Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.xmldataprovider.source.aspx) property to a path from a file dialog.

For example:

```
var provider = (XmlDataProvider)this.Resources["organization"];
var dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
dialog.Filter = "XML Files|*.xml";
if (dialog.ShowDialog(this)) {
    provider.Source = new Uri(dialog.FileName, UriKind.Absolute);
```